# Lie operator is left exact

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

In page 190, part (c) of the book "Algebraic groups, the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field" of Milne, there's a part stating that:

> An exact sequence of algebraic groups $e \rightarrow G' \rightarrow G \rightarrow G''$ gives an exact sequence of Lie algebras $0 \rightarrow Lie(G') \rightarrow Lie(G) \rightarrow Lie(G'')$.

This is what I tried so far: Because every algebraic group is affine over some base field, the exact algebraic groups sequence gives the exact Hopf algebras sequence $0 \rightarrow A' \rightarrow A \rightarrow A''$. If we can obtain from this sequence the sequence $0 \rightarrow I_A/I_A^2 \rightarrow I_{A'}/I_{A'}^2 \rightarrow I_{A''}/I_{A''}^2$, then we are done, because $Lie(G) \cong Hom(I_G/I_G^2, k)$, and the Hom functor is left exact.

But I can't prove that missing point. I would be glad if anyone can give me any hint. Thanks a lot.

Edited: From the hint of @anon, I post here where I stuck right now:

Because we have an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow Lie(G) \rightarrow G(k[\epsilon]) \rightarrow G(k)$$ and $G$ is an left-exact functor, we have this diagram:
[image]

Here all the rows are exact due to what we state above, and two last columns are exact due to left-exactness of G. So we need to prove that the first column is also exact. I think maybe this is some property from commutative algebra related to five lemma, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: 1) the maps on Hopf algebras go the other way, and
2) there isn't an exact sequence of Hopf algebras (what would this mean for rings? a ring map sends 1 to 1)

Comment: Use a diagram chase. For example, if an element of $Lie(G')$ maps to zero in $Lie(G)$, then it maps to zero in $G(k[\varepsilon])$, hence it maps to zero in $G'(k[\varepsilon])$, and hence is zero.

Comment: @anon: i can prove it now. Do you know any resource where can I find general statement about the relation of the exactness of rows and sequences like this? Like a book or article. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, there is an exact sequence
$0\to\text{Lie}(G)\to G(k[\varepsilon]) \to G(k)$. For each $k$-algebra $R$, the functor $G \mapsto G(R)$ is left exact, from which the statement follows by a diagram chase in the obvious diagram.

Comment: Can you explain further? How can you obtain the conclusion from the exact sequence and the left exactness of the functor?